# Which language L have exactly one equivalence class

Tags: equivalence-relations, regular-language

Consider the alphabet {a,b}, for which language does the equivalence relation R have exactly one equivalence  class?

From what i understand about equivalence class, each state is consider a class. So would $a^n : n \ge 0$ be the one class ?
Can someone help me understand where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the Nerode equivalence relation: ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem))
$$
x \sim_L y \iff (\forall z \in \Sigma^*: \ xz \in L \iff yz \in L)
$$